# How to get thei requester IP on a Spring webapp running on AWS ElasticBeastalk Application Load Balancer

Tags: java, spring, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a web app written in Java using Spring as a backend framework.
This application is running on AWS ElasticBeanstalk with an Application Load Balancer. I was wondering how can I get the IP of all the users sending requests to my web app.

[EDIT 1]
I noticed that just by doing this I correctly get my ip address.

```
@GetMapping
public String processData(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr());

}
```

I don't know if there are particular cases in which this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable access logs on ALB which will record all requests to ALB. Info recorded: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) 
If you have some compliance requirements, don't forget to rotate the logs (s3 lifecycle) accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But how can I use this log then? I would like to store the page visits and use them... how can I do that with the solution you gave me?

Answer (score 0):

`request.getRemoteAddr();` pretty much sums it up. You can do the same for the port and other properties as well.